# Toggle style properties with JavaScript by commenting-out CSS attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to send a list of properties to a function that will temporarily disable (via comments) those properties.  The purpose is similar to what is accomplished by Chrome Dev Tools when inspecting the style of an element, except that the user will not check/uncheck boxes, instead, the action will be performed by JavaScript.

```
function disableProperties(el, properties) {
    var property; // property value pair
    var cssStr = el.style.cssText.replace(/; /g, ";");

    for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        property = properties[i] + ": " + eval("el.style." + properties[i]) + ";";
        cssStr = cssStr.replace(property, "/* " + property + " */");
    }

    el.setAttribute("style", cssStr);
}

function restoreProperties(el, properties) {
    var outHtml = el.outerHTML;
    var key = 'style="';
    var idx1 = outHtml.indexOf(key) + key.length;
    var idx2 = outHtml.indexOf('"', idx1);
    var style = outHtml.substring(idx1, idx2);

    for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        str = "/* " + properties[i];
        let a = style.indexOf(str);
        let b = style.indexOf(" */", a + a.length) + 3;
        let comment = style.substring(a, b);
        let property = (comment).replace("/*", "").replace("*/", "");

        style = style.replace(comment, property);
    }

    el.style.cssText = style;
}
```

When elements are created, their style is embedded in the HTML instead of external CSS files.  It is important that the properties are only temporarily disabled; their earlier values must be preserved.

UPDATE:
I thought my comment code was not working because I was trying to retrieve the comment by asking for `el.style.cssText`; however, the comment was only available through `outerHTML`.

The code below is functional, but I'm sure that could be cleaned up.  If you have suggestions on how I can improve this code, please advise.  Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NaFinGrn7/15vpjuam/86/) to demonstrate one example of how I am using the code.

Comment: Properties are correctly commented out (and not deleted) for me in Chrome, with the code you posted. [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/HyWex4D), [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1qco35b/)

Comment: @NathanGreen I've deleted my answer because I don't think it's what you're looking for, based on your comments on it. You mentioned that you'll be editing the question so I'll wait for that and see if I can provide a more relevant answer based on your edit.

Comment: @blex thank you for letting me know that my code worked, I was trying to retrieve it with JS instead of inspecting it.  My code to retrieve comments was the problem.

Comment: @volt thank you for you code suggestions; I was able to learn from your code to improve other areas of my own.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Volts deleted answer, use data attributes to store the initial state of your element. You can then that information to reset the values. One catch is that the `style` property is [read only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), so if we want to reset all style properties, we have to loop all the properties.

This is much cleaner than hacking comments in and out. This works with styles set inline and with classes.

```js
const disableProperties = (el, properties) => {
  //store the style so we can restore it
  
  el.dataset.styles = JSON.stringify(el.style);
  console.log(JSON.parse(el.dataset.styles));
  properties.forEach(property => {
    el.style[property] = "unset";
  })
}

const enableProperties = (el, properties) => {
  //Get our saved initial state
  let styles = JSON.parse(el.dataset.styles);
  console.log(styles);
  properties.forEach(property => {
    el.style[property] = styles[property];
  })
}

const restoreAll = (el) => {   
  let styles = JSON.parse(el.dataset.styles);
  console.log(styles);
  /*You might think the following line should work, but the styles property is read only*/
  /*el.style = styles;*/
  /*So loop our properties instead*/
  for(prop in styles){
    if(styles.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      el.style[prop] = styles[prop];
    }    
  }
}

document.querySelector('.child').addEventListener("click", function() {
  disableProperties(this.parentNode, ["top", "left"])
})

let enableButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".enable");

for (var i = 0; i < enableButtons.length; i++) {
  enableButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    let property = this.dataset.restore;
    let target = document.querySelector(this.dataset.target);
    enableProperties(target, property.split(","));
  });
}

document.getElementById("restoreAll").addEventListener("click", function() {
  restoreAll(document.querySelector(".parent"));
});
```

```css
.parent {
  /*top: 50px;*/
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {position:relative; height:200px;}
```

```html
Click the square before restoring

<div class="container">
  <div class="parent" style="top:50px;">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="restoreLeft" class="enable" data-restore="left" data-target=".parent">Restore Left</button>
<button id="restoreTop" class="enable" data-restore="top" data-target=".parent">Restore top</button>
<button id="restoreAll">RestoreAll</button>
```